# How to do a safe and_then in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I remember there was an "and_then" operator in VAX-Pascal. I miss it in Delphi-Pascal. What is the best way to do a safe check in Delphi?

From https://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/and_005fthen.html:

“The and_then short-circuit logical operator performs the same operation as the logical operator and. But while the ISO standard does not specify anything about the evaluation of the operands of and – they may be evaluated in any order, or not at all – and_then has a well-defined behaviour: It evaluates the first operand. If the result is False, and_then returns False without evaluating the second operand. If it is True, the second operand is evaluated and returned.”

As an example I have a StringList and want to check if first element has the value 'ID'. And of course I can only check first element if the list is not empty.
The long and safe way:

```
xlst := TStringList.Create;
if (xlst.Count > 0) then
begin
   if (xlst[0] = 'ID') then ShowMessage(xlst[0])
end
else ShowMessage('String list is empty');
```

Is there a shorter way to do?

Test 1:

```
xlst := TStringList.Create;
if (xlst.Count > 0) and (xlst[0] := 'ID') then ShowMessage(xlst[0])
else ShowMessage('String list is empty');
```

It works but is it safe? Is the second test only executed if the first is true? Can I rely on that the order of execution is the order written in the code?

Test 2:

```
xlst := TStringList.Create;
if (xlst[0] = 'ID') and (xlst.Count > 0) then ShowMessage(xlst[0])
else ShowMessage('String list is empty');
```

As expected this code will lead to an error at runtime.

Comment: Look at "Boolean short-circuit evaluation" compiler directive. *In the {$B-} state, the compiler generates code for short-circuit Boolean expression evaluation, which means that evaluation stops as soon as the result of the entire expression becomes evident in left to right order of evaluation.* `{$B-} {$BOOLEVAL OFF}` is default.

Comment: As you said, the Test2 will lead to an error, even with  `{$B-}`. The cure is to always test `Count` first as you do in Test1. It is safe in the default `{$B-}` state.

Comment: The compiler switch mentioned by @TomBrunberg is also available in the project options -> compiler!